# How do I only allow one instance of an SKSpriteNode on screen at one time?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

This is my first ever post - I have searched for a long time and could not find the answer.

I am making a game with SpriteKit and want the player to be able to only launch one bomb at a time- i.e they can't fire again until the previous bomb has exploded or gone off screen. Currently when the player taps the screen, they can launch as many bombs as they want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Iain

Comment: Keep an `Optional<SKSpriteNode>` variable on the player that keeps reference to the bomb the player has launched and is in flight. Set it whenever a bomb is launched, and unset it whenever a bomb explodes. Only allow launching new bombs if the variable is already nil

Comment: Is your game physics based or action based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve's idea works out well and is better than mine, but here is a more novice-friendly explanation IMO... Put this in your gamescene :)

```
var canFireMissile = true

func fireMissile() {
  guard canFireMissile else { return }

  canFireMissile = false   // So you can't fire anymore missiles until 0.5secs later

  let wait     = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.5) // the duration of the missile animation (example)
  let reset    = SKAction.run { canFireMissile = true } // lets us refire the missile
  let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, reset])
  run(sequence)
}

override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) { // touchesBegan on iOS
  fireMissile()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help- this made things a lot clearer!

Comment: I actually prefer this approach over Steve,  checking a boolean state is a lot faster than checking if a key exists in a hash table

Comment: only change I would make, is attach the action to the missile or use a completion handler to avoid the wait

Answer (score 1):

Create a SKSpriteNode property for your misssile. 
Create an SKAction for the movement of the missile and give the action a key so you can refer to it by name).
When the fire button is pressed, check to see if the named action is already running; if it is, do nothing, otherwise run the ‘fireMissile’ action.

Comment: I like this a lot - will give it a go! Thanks!